# Swift: sort key value pairs in array of dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have to sort an array of dictinaries for my first project (online course). Sort has not been covered and I was left to do some research myself. Did go to Apple and read about closures, watched youtube to understand the concept of sorting but I am still a little confused on how to setup the logic for that (func I am assuming)

This is the collection I have so far

```
var players: [[String: Any]] = [

        ["Name": "Joe Smith",
        "Height": 42,
        "Experience": true,
        "Guardians": "Jime and Jan Smith",
        "Team": ""],

        ["Name": "Jill Tanner",
        "Height": 36,
        "Experience": true,
        "Guardians": "Clara Tanner",
        "Team": ""],

        ["Name": "Bill Bon",
        "Height": 43,
        "Experience": true,
        "Guardians": "Sara and Jenny Bon",
        "Team": ""],
]
```

Any tips or source would be great thanks!

Comment: Well, what do you want to sort by?

Comment: If this is for a class, are you allowed to use built-in sort functions, or do you have to write your own?

Comment: Please do some [basic searching on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+sort+array+of+dictionary) before posting. This has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply - the project is to sort the soccer players in to 3 teams, ensure that experienced players are equilly devided, and height should be within 1.5 inches. The second logic will need to write a letter to all parents including there first day of training and time. There are 18 players total. It is pretty basic stuff I have covered so far collections, control flow, and functions.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you convert your data into an Array of structs (or perhaps objects), rather than an Array of dictionaries. The weak typing necessary to use Dictionary (i.e. having `Any` as the type of the values) makes dictionaries really annoying to work with. Plus there's also the  massive hit you take to performance and safety when working with Dictionaries.

```
struct Player {
    let name: String
    let height: Int
    let experience: Bool
    let guardians: String
    let team: String?
}

let players = [
    Player(
        name: "Joe Smith",
        height: 42,
        experience: true,
        guardians: "Jime and Jan Smith",
        team: nil
    ),
    Player(
        name: "Jill Tanner",
        height: 36,
        experience: true,
        guardians: "Clara Tanner",
        team: nil
    ),
    Player(
        name: "Bill Bon",
        height: 43,
        experience: true,
        guardians: "Sara and Jenny Bon",
        team: nil
    ),
]

// Example, sort by height

let sortedPlayers = players.sorted{ $0.height < $1.height }

for player in sortedPlayers {
    print(player)
}
```

I've provided the `sorted` method of `Array` a closure which tells it how to perform a comparison between any two given elements. In this example, I've written a closure that puts shorter players before taller players.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your input! At this point, I am not familiar with struct and from my understanding the online course suggests to utilize as much as possible material that has been covered during class (collections, control flow, and functions) Yet, I will study "Struct" to get a better understanding of what it is capable of.